# Vue app custom scss file - change font across entire app?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to change the app across the entire vue app, I have a custom scss file that is imported into main.ts in the app. So far I have this but don't think its working any suggestions?

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #5e72e4,
);
$vue-slider-mark-label: (
  "font-size": 18px,
);

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

$body-font-family: 'Montserrat';
$font-size-root: 14px !default;

v-app {
  font-family: $body-font-family !important;
}

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss";
```

Comment: also tried: @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900&display=swap");
$body-font-family: "Maven Pro" !important;

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do can be achieved by importing your google font inside of your `<style>` tag, in best case, in `App.vue`, your main component.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
```

Then you can use it like this. Please not to not `scope` this attributes:

```
html, body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```